# Macro to Copy and paste from one sheet into next open column in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am new to vba and don't know how to code. I recorded a macro to copy specified cells from one sheet into cells in another sheet, but it keeps pasting into the same column and  I want the paste to be into the next open column. This is all I have.

Sub Weekday()
'
' Weekday Macro
'

```
Range("J10:J13").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select
Range("C2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Hint...using the recorder, try Ctrl+Right Arrow to find the last used column.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Sheets("Results")
    .Cells(2, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Resize(4).Value = Range("J10:J13").Value
End With
```

Comment: Do I replace Sheets("Results").Select with what you added? it is giving me an error

Comment: This is what I have and I am getting an application defined error Sheets("Daily Snapshot").Select
With Sheets("Results")
    .Range(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Resize(4).Value = Range("J10:J13").Value
End With

Comment: sorry, I mistyped `Cells` with `Range`: see edited code

Answer (score 0):

If you change :

```
Range("C2").Select
```

by

```
c = Cells(2, 3).End(xlToRight).Column + 1
Cells(2, c).Select
```

c is an integer. It gives you the number of the next empty column in the row 2.